# Rspec not found when running from shell script

Tags: ruby, shell, rspec

I'm trying to write a shell script to execute my rspecs in a project, but the script gives the error `rspec: not found`.

This is the script...

```
#!/bin/sh
command rspec spec spec/pos_spec.rb
$SHELL
```

...outputs

```
/home/joebloggs/GitHub/repo/test: 2: /home/joebloggs/GitHub/repo/test: rspec: not found
```

The line `rspec spec repo/pos_spec.rb` works if I type it directly into the shell, so I'm not sure why it can't find rspec. How can I get this to work?

Comment: `echo $PATH` in the script to see if it contains a path to `which rspec`. Try using the `bash` shebang in case `sh` isn't alised to it, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. If you project uses it also consider `bundle exec rspec ...`. And finally not sure what the `command` command is for, is it needed?

Comment: The `echo $PATH` within the script is a list half as big as when I do it from within the terminal, and it's missing all the ruby stuff. Any ideas why it's using a different PATH?

Comment: It must be loading a different environment, e.g. it might not be sourcing `.bashrc` / `.profile`, which is why I suggested the different shebang.

Comment: The bash shebang has the same stunted path list. And although I have bundle it isn't recognised as a valid command, presumably for the same reason rspec isn't working. Perhaps I should start (or look for) a new question as to how I get a shell script with access to my PATH variable.

Comment: You can try to `source ~/.bashrc` after the shebang. But yes, I think this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'rspec spec/models/employers_spec.rb' > my_shell.sh
$ sh my_shell.sh
```

**Output:**

```
Finished in 4.48 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
Randomized with seed 9820
```

Comment: If I try this the terminal doesn't show, and it deletes the content of my shell script.

Comment: are you using windows machine or linux/mac machine?
Note: above one works perfectly for me though.

Comment: Linux Mint 18 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda got it to work, and thought I'd share.

If I double click on the sh file, it opens a terminal, but fails. And I determined that it was due to the PATH variable being incomplete. More specifically it was missing these entries...

```
/home/joebloggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:
/home/joebloggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:
/home/joebloggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:
```

However, if I then used the exact same terminal that failed the script because it couldn't find the rspec command, and then ran `./test.sh`, it worked. I could also directly type `rspec spec spec/pos_spec.rb` and it would also work. So it just seems that starting the script from a double click changes the PATH variable momentarily?

Anyway, I wont mark this as the correct answer, as it doesn't solve the original problem.

**TLDR:** Don't double click the sh file, run it from terminal using `./script.sh`.